# How to update the TTL on a collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

Using NodeJS + MongoJS, I have connection to a mongo DB.

I set a TTL on a collection with:

```
myCollection.createIndex({createdAt: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 60 * 30})
```

Is it now possible to update the value for expireAfterSeconds ?
If so, what's the policy for already existing items in the collection, ie : are their TTL updated automatically or are they left untouched ?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/modify-an-index/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot actually "update" an index definition. What you need to here is "delete" the index and then "re-create" it. So use [`.dropIndex()`](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#dbcollectiondropindexindex-callback) first

```js
myCollection.dropIndex({ "createdAt": 1 },function(err,result) { });
```

Then recreate with a new interval:

```js
myCollection.ensureIndex(
   { "createdAt": 1 },
   { "expireAfterSeconds": 60 * 10 },
   function(err,result) { }
);
```

As for when it updates, the `mongod` service runs at an interval every 60 seconds an event you process a delete for any items where the effective date field ( i.e "createdAt" in this example ) is within the "expiry period" from the current time of the server.

So that means it does not matter if you drop the index and re-create it, as the existing server process will just run the same expiry query on each collection that has such an index defined on that interval clock.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and can cause issues (downtime of no index and performance while rebuilding). You CANm change the index TTL see - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collMod/#mongodb-collflag-index

Answer (score 10):

Apart of the @Neil answer above, the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) states, that

> You cannot use `createIndex()` to change the value of `expireAfterSeconds` of an existing index. Instead use the `collMod` database command in conjunction with the `index` collection flag. Otherwise, to change the value of the option of an existing index, you must drop the index first and recreate.

So

```js
db.runCommand({
  "collMod": <collection>,
  "index": {
    keyPattern: <index_spec>,
    expireAfterSeconds: <seconds>
  }
})
```

should work fine too.

Answer (score 3):

From: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

> You can modify the expireAfterSeconds of an existing TTL index using the collMod command.

See Rob's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30174928/6088194

Rob's method worked for me. I updated the TTL index from weeks to 2 minutes and the previously loaded in documents started to be removed from the database once they exceeded the new expiration period.

**EDIT:** note that if authentication is enabled for Mongo then the '[collMod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collMod/#dbcmd.collMod)' command requires [dbAdmin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdmin) or [adAminAnyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdminAnyDatabase) privileges